# Optimise excel VBA code - combine resident address

Tags: vba, excel

I have done the following 2 VBA code in excel. Main purpose is to combine multiple address rows into a single line. Problem is it takes forever to run. Is there anyway I can optimise it?

The data is as such, there is a case# for each of the customer address. The customer address can be split into multiple rows. Example: "Address row 1 - Block 56", "Address row 2 - Parry Avenue", "address row 3 - Postal code". There is a blank space between each new address.

My purpose is to combine the address into a single line, and remove the empty rows in between the case numbers eg "Block 56 Parry Avenue Postal code". There are approx 26K case numbers.

```
Sub test()


Dim l As Long
Dim lEnd As Long
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim temp As String

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wks = Sheets("data")
wks.Activate

lEnd = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For l = 3 To lEnd
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(l, 1)) Then
            Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(l + 1, 4))
                temp = Cells(l, 4).Value & " " & Cells(l + 1, 4).Value
                Cells(l, 4).Value = temp
                Cells(l + 1, 4).EntireRow.Delete
            Loop

    Else: Cells(l, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(l + 1, 4))
                temp = Cells(l, 4).Value & " " & Cells(l + 1, 4).Value
                Cells(l, 4).Value = temp
                Cells(l + 1, 4).EntireRow.Delete
            Loop
    End If


Next l

End Sub
```

and the 2nd code I tried

```
Sub transformdata()
'
Dim temp As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Range("A3").Select

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) And IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3))
            temp = ActiveCell.Offset(, 3).Value & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Value
            ActiveCell.Offset(, 3).Value = temp
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).EntireRow.Delete
     Loop

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share us a picture(s) of your worksheet and your sample data? It'd help to understand your request

Comment: How many columns are there?  Is there only 4 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the line `lEnd = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`. Incorrect way of finding last row. You may want to see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)
2. To delete rows where `Cells(l, 1)` is empty, use Autofilter. See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-condition)
3. Do not delete rows in a straight loop. Use a reverse loop. Or what you could do is identify the cells that you want to delete in a loop and then delete them in one go after the loop. You may want to see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077945/delete-cells-in-an-excel-column-when-rows-0)

Here is a basic example.

Let's say your worksheet looks like this

[image]

If you run this code

```
Sub test()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim temp As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wks = Sheets("data")

    With wks
        '~~> Find Last Row
        lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
            If Len(Trim(.Range("C" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                If temp = "" Then
                    temp = .Range("C" & i).Value
                Else
                    temp = .Range("C" & i).Value & "," & temp
                End If
            Else
                .Range("D" & i + 1).Value = temp
                temp = ""
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

You will get this output

[image]

Now simply run the autofilter to delete the rows where Col D is empty :) I have already give you the link above for the same.

Comment: You need to turn`Application.ScreenUpdating` back on.

Comment: No it goes back on after sub ends

Comment: @ThomasInzina: Yup you are right. The above is a part of the main code. At the end the screenupdating needs to be turned back on :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I tried to use the autofilter to delete the rows. It takes very long to complete. The code I'm using as below. Can you please tell me whats wrong? `With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
  .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
  .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With `

Comment: I have resolved it by sorting the blanks to the bottom before deleting. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The code below will copy all the data into an array, consolidate it, and add it to a new worksheet.  You'll need to make COLUMNCOUNT = the number of columns that contain data.

[image]

```
Sub TransformData2()
    Const COLUMNCOUNT = 4
    Dim SourceData, NewData
    Dim count As Long, x1 As Long, x2 As Long, y As Long

    SourceData = Range("A" & Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row, Cells(3, COLUMNCOUNT))

    For x1 = 1 To UBound(SourceData, 1)

        count = count + 1
        If count = 1 Then
            ReDim NewData(1 To 4, 1 To count)
        Else
            ReDim Preserve NewData(1 To 4, 1 To count)
        End If

        For y = 1 To UBound(SourceData, 2)
            NewData(y, count) = SourceData(x1, y)
        Next

        x2 = x1 + 1

        Do
            NewData(4, count) = NewData(4, count) & " " & SourceData(x2, 4)
            x2 = x2 + 1
            If x2 > UBound(SourceData, 1) Then Exit Do
        Loop Until IsEmpty(SourceData(x2, 4))
        x1 = x2
    Next

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(NewData, 2), UBound(NewData, 1)).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(NewData)
End Sub
```